# Change VisualStudio 2015 Key Bindings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a new little keyboard without key F 11 and F 12. In my case this keys is very often to use.I wont to change this key for example F 11 to F 8 and F 12 to F 9. How can make this on easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard

You can modify, add, and remove key bindings there.

See [*Identifying and Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx) and [*Visual Studio 2015 keyboard shortcuts: The complete list*](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/).

Comment: Thx this is work , but i install programm call SharpKey 
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/
With this program i change the key in windows level, because without F 12 I cant run even page inspector.

Comment: @DTodorov That would work, but remember there are useful key bindings already associated to all the function keys (eg. F9 sets a breakpoint, F12 goes to definition). With fewer keys you'll have to be more selective about your shortcuts,

Comment: Yes it is a matter of preference.