# Visual Studio 2019: Insert multiple C++ style single-line comments

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 Community (v16.6.1). When editing C/C++/C# code, select several lines of code:

```
int countLines = 0;
if (!editingDocument)
    countLines = GetDocumentLines();
```

Now trigger `Edit.ToggleBlockComment` (`Ctrl+Shift+/`), or `Edit.ToggleLineComment` (`Ctrl+K, Ctrl+/`). In both cases, "C style" comments are applied:

```
/*int countLines = 0;
if (!editingDocument)
    countLines = GetDocumentLines();*/
```

This is ok, but I actually wanted C++ style, single-line comments:

```
// int countLines = 0;
// if (!editingDocument)
//     countLines = GetDocumentLines();
```

Is this possible? Ideal would be `Edit.ToggleBlockComment` to use "C style" and `Edit.ToggleLineComment` to use "C++ style".

#### Update

Thanks to one of the comments, I can confirm that when there is at least one comment inside the selected block, VS is smart enough to use C++ single-line comments for the whole block. While this doesn't answer the question, it is a useful workaround for now.

Comment: For me, both `Ctrl+Shift+/`,`Ctrl+K+/`, and `Ctrl+K+C` do the line comments, unless only a portion of one of the lines is selected.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think I have come across any such setting myself in the options. And it is tied to individual language service implementations, so you would need to request this feature - in case it is indeed absent - from all of those languages you are interested in.

Comment: Don't know about C# but, in C/C++ code, if the selected block *already* has even one `//` comment in it, then the whole block is commented-out with `//` at the start of each line. Maybe helpful.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Aha, great catch! Hadn't spotted that. Can confirm that if there is at least one comment inside the selection, VS is smart enough to use C++ single-line comments for the whole block. That's a good enough workaround for now, thanks! Have added that as an update to the question.

Comment: For me, Ctrl+K+/ toggles single-line comments, Ctrl+K+C adds a layer of single-line comments, and Ctrl+K+U removes a layer of single-line comments. Unsure why this doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in editor by selecting text column via `Shift + Alt + Up/Down arrow` then just type `//`

Comment: Yes, that works. This is the "column select" method that has been in Notepad++ for years. A nice addition to Visual Studio. Using a mouse, press `Alt` and drag a vertical column with the mouse, then type `//` to achieve the same result. While not an answer to the specific question (where the answer appears to be "This feature is not available"), this is a decent workaround.

Comment: It has been in various editors for decades and not new in VS either. This is how I comment out code blocks. Same number of key presses and nothing new to remember.

Comment: Great find! It's just `column editing`, which has been in various editors (notably, the great Notepad++) for decades, applied to this particular problem. Note: It also works with the mouse. Put the cursor at the top (or bottom) of the column you want to create, press `Shift + Alt`, then move the mouse, and insert or delete the `/` characters

Answer (score 0):

You can get the following...

- Click anywhere in a line, and toggle "//" comments
- Select multiple lines, and toggle "//" comments
- Preserve previously commented sub-sections
- With a single key combination, eg `Ctrl-/`

By setting the command `Edit.ToggleLineComment` to `Ctrl-/` in the [keyboard editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737449/change-visualstudio-2015-key-bindings).

This is identical functionality to Eclipse, IntelliJ and Android Studio. Once you've got it into your fingers anything else is clumsy.